# Why does this C++ code work? (probably simple)

Tags: c++

I am was learning some very basic C++ when I stumbled upon some code that shouldn't work but.. . it does!

Here is a very simple version of what I found:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string HelloWorld();

int main(){
    cout << HelloWorld();
}

string HelloWorld(){
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Why does this work?? I am printing something that isn't declared yet. It should print nothing.

Comment: What part of it do you think shouldn't work?

Comment: all looks valid to me. HelloWorld returns a string which cout expects

Comment: It is declared - `string HelloWorld();` is a declaration - but it's not defined. But that's fine: the compiler and linker will find the code that defines `HelloWorld`. Try removing the function definition and see what happens.

Comment: Why does it return "Hello World" if the function isn't set to return "Hello World" till later in the code.

Comment: Please learn the fundamentals of C++.

Comment: Oh, right... Thanks! (I feel like an idiot now).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is totally correct.

```
string HelloWorld();
```

Here you're telling the compiler: "Hey, this function called `HelloWorld` exists somewhere. It takes no parameters and returns a string.  This is called the function **declaration**. You're declaring that it exists. It's specifically referred to as a [**forward declaration**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration).

```
int main(){
    cout << HelloWorld();
}
```

Now when you call `HelloWorld` here, the compiler knows it exists somewhere, because you told it it would.

```
string HelloWorld(){
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Here you're actually **defining** the function. You're telling the compiler: "This is what I meant when I said `HelloWorld` existed somewhere.

When the program is compiled, it happens in several passes, each of which satisfies more requirements for the program to be built. In the end, it *doesn't really matter* where the code is. Provided everything exists, it is the *linker's* job to (unsurprisingly) link everything together, and point `main` to `HelloWorld`, even though it is after `main` in your C file.

Perhaps you're a Python or PHP programmer?

Remember, C is nothing like these languages, in that C is a compiled language - every function that will ever exist in the program's lifetime exists at the moment it is finished being built.

Comment: And very true, I have only currently programmed with Python and JavaScript in the past.

Answer (score 1):

At the call site, the compiler only needs a declaration.  In this case `HelloWorld()` is forward declared before it is called.

It's the job of the linker to ensure all the required definitions are pulled in.  If everything had to be fully defined at the point of its use, the language would be much more difficult to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling a function that *has* been declared, and printing its return value.

The function hasn't been *defined* yet; but you only need a declaration to call it. The definition could even be in another source file, linked with this one after compilation; it would still work, and return whatever its definition says it should return.

Answer (score 1):

This code has only one defect. It has to have included header `<string>` Otherwise other compilers can issue an error.:)

So the program should contain directive

```
#include <string>
```

You are printing what was already defined. You are printing the return value of function `HelloWorld` that is declared before its call

```
string HelloWorld();
```

In its definition the function has return statement that returns string literal "Hello World"

```
string HelloWorld(){
    return "Hello World";
}
```

As the class `std::string`has constructor that accepts a string literal as an argument then an object of type `std::string` is created as the return value and you are printing it.

Comment: I was just looking to see if anyone mentioned the missing header. The fact is that my version of Visual Studio will spit at that code.